# Modifying code to allow for multiple entries in x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to modify the code for the following function so as to allow for multiple entries in `x` (i.e. I want to query multiple points at once)?

```
def banana(x):
    return exp(((-x[0]**2/200))-0.5*(x[1]+0.05*(x[0]**2) - 100*0.05)**2)
```

Comment: Why not just call that function multiple times?

Comment: Yes. In that case you better use numpy though.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the function, consider using the built-in `map` functions to apply the function to all elements in a collection. In this the implementation of `banana` is kept simple. Below is an example of how to use the `map` function.

```
entries = [...]
mapped_entries = map(banana, entries)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy`.  It appears that your function uses a pair of numbers (`x[0]` and `x[1]`).  This is represented in numpy using a two dimensional array of numbers (`n x 2`):

```
import numpy as np

def apple(x):  # Note that `x` is an array, not a tuple pair.
    return np.exp((((-x[0]**2/200)) - 0.5 * (x[1] + 0.05 * x[0]**2 - 100 * 0.05) ** 2))

x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> apple(x)
array([ 0.23427726,  0.36059494,  0.12857409])
```